# Plug-in handled load WebKitErrorDomain 204 error on WKWebView below iOS 15

Tags: ios, video, html5-video, wkwebview, mp4

I am loading some URL to WKWebView, for instance, https://example.com/123123/example.mp4.

The URL points to video. Above iOS 15, everything is fine, video is playing on WKWebView. But below iOS 15, there is an error `WebKitErrorDomain=204, Plug-in handled`. load. I got it from `didFailNavigationWithError` method. WKWebview shows just disabled play icon.

I tried to open my link on Safari on Mac. It couldn't play that video. Chrome could.

I tried to open my link on Safari below iOS 15. It couldn't play that video. On iOS 15 is everything ok.

What can be the reason for this error? How to fix it? I found other questions about this topic on SO, but none of them helped.